# merge sort python implementation methodology

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm learning the well known sorting algorithms and implementing them myself. I have recently done merge sort and the code I have is:

```
def merge(l, r, direction):
    # print('merging')
    # print(l, r)
    # adding infinity to end of list so we know when we've hit the bottom of one pile
    l.append(inf)
    r.append(inf)
    A = []
    i, j = 0, 0

    while (i < len(l)) and (j < len(r)):
        if l[i] <= r[j]:
            A.append(l[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            A.append(r[j])
            j += 1
    # removing infinity from end of list
    A.pop()

    return(A)


def merge_sort(num_lst, direction='increasing', level=0):
    if len(num_lst) > 1:
        mid = len(num_lst)//2
        l = num_lst[:mid]
        r = num_lst[mid:]
        l = merge_sort(l, level=level + 1)
        r = merge_sort(r, level=level + 1)
        num_lst = merge(l, r, direction)

    return num_lst
```

What I have seen in other implementations that differs from my own is in the merging of lists. Where I just create a blank list and append elements in numerical order other pass the preexisting into merge and overwrite each element to create a list in numerical order. Something like:

```
def merge(arr, l, m, r): 
    n1 = m - l + 1
    n2 = r- m 
  
    # create temp arrays 
    L = [0] * (n1) 
    R = [0] * (n2) 
  
    # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] 
    for i in range(0 , n1): 
        L[i] = arr[l + i] 
  
    for j in range(0 , n2): 
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j] 
  
    # Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r] 
    i = 0     # Initial index of first subarray 
    j = 0     # Initial index of second subarray 
    k = l     # Initial index of merged subarray 
  
    while i < n1 and j < n2 : 
        if L[i] <= R[j]: 
            arr[k] = L[i] 
            i += 1
        else: 
            arr[k] = R[j] 
            j += 1
        k += 1
  
    # Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there 
    # are any 
    while i < n1: 
        arr[k] = L[i] 
        i += 1
        k += 1
  
    # Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there 
    # are any 
    while j < n2: 
        arr[k] = R[j] 
        j += 1
        k += 1
```

I'm curious about the following:

## Problem

Is using a `append()` on a blank list a bad idea? By my understanding when python creates a list it grabs a certain size chunk of memory and if our list grows beyond that copies the list to a different and larger section of memory (which seems it would be pretty high cost if it happened even once for a large list let alone repeatedly).
Is there just a higher cost to using `append()` compared to accessing a list by index? It would seemed to me append would be able to do things at a fairly low cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate a list Python will allocate the memory necessary for holding the items plus some extra memory for future appends / extends. When you put too much extra stuff in the list it eventually needs to be reallocated which potentially slows down the program (see [this part](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/87b6078fb90f11dc67ad8f31e98cbc40f74fcb81/Objects/listobject.c#L292) of the source code). The reallocation happens [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/87b6078fb90f11dc67ad8f31e98cbc40f74fcb81/Objects/listobject.c#L59) and the size is calculated as:

```
new_allocated = (size_t)newsize + (newsize >> 3) + (newsize < 9 ? 3 : 6);
```

As [the comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/87b6078fb90f11dc67ad8f31e98cbc40f74fcb81/Objects/listobject.c#L55) states the growth pattern is: `0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...`.

So if the size of the final list is known in advance and allocated from the beginning this will save you some extra reallocations (and thus compute time).

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import time 
append_arr = []
index_arr = [None] * 10240*1024

t0 = time()
for x in range(10240*1024):
    append_arr.append(x)
t1 = time()

t2 = time()
for i in range(10240*1024):
    index_arr[i] = i
t3 = time()

print(str(t1-t0))
print(str(t3-t2))
```

Looks like appending is slower.

Comment: You should move `append_arr = []
index_arr = [None] * 10240*1024` inside your timing just in case the time to initialise the large array has an impact.

Comment: I've already done this testing. To clarify, my question is whether or not I understand the way lists are managed in python and why ```append()``` would end up being slower?